# Python - Pandasql - IIf Function doesn't work Error

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, ms-access, pandasql

Trying to execute the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,6,7], 'B':[7,8,9]})
print(df)

       A  B
    0  5  7
    1  6  8
    2  7  9

qry = """SELECT df.*, IIf(A Is Null,[B],[A]) AS NEW_A FROM df;"""
df1 = ps.sqldf(qry, globals())
print(df1)
```

yields this error:

```
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: IIf 
[SQL: 'SELECT df.*, IIf(A Is Null,[B],[A]) AS NEW_A FROM df;']
```

I've tried various combinations of different syntax regarding square brackets, globals/locals etc. but couldn't find the issue. Is this function simply not existing?

I simply copied the SQL query from an MS Access query but for other cases this works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `iif()` function in **SQLite**.
In this case you can use [`coalesce()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce):

```
SELECT df.*, coalesce(A, B) AS NEW_A FROM df
```

The functionality of `iif()` can be achieved with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT df.*, CASE WHEN A is null THEN B ELSE A END AS NEW_A FROM df
```

but in this case `coalesce()` is simpler.

**UPDATE**: 
Starting from version **3.32.0** of SQLite (**2020-05-22**) the function [`iif()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#iif) is supported.

Comment: Thank you! As this was just a simplifying example, I actually need the CASE statement. Also thank you for the reference to SQLite, in future I will first look there.

Comment: Can you comment then why the SQLite documentation lists an IIF function? Here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#iif

Comment: @MarcinWojnarski as of version 3.32.0 of SQLite (2020-05-22) function `iif()` is supported. Check here the Release history: https://sqlite.org/changes.html. It's time to edit my answer.